# update RecyclerView after fetching data from server

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I´ve got a problem with my RecyclerView. I want to update the Cards (inside the RecyclerView) after fetching the data from the server. First I thought there´s a problem with fetching or parsing the JSON-data, or sending the data via EventBus to the Fragment but when I display the parsed Objects in a TextView in the Fragment, everything is shown up. So the real problem is the RecyclerView / Adapter. 
I´ve initialized the RecyclerView with an empty ArrayList, but when and HOW do I have to update the data for the RecyclerView? I´ve also read some Posts here on Stackoverflow, but I found no suitable solution...

This is the **onCreateView** from UserFragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.rv_user);
    //set LayoutManager for View
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    //set Adapter for View
    mAdapter = new UserAdapter(userList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    return mView;
}
```

and this is my **UserAdapter**

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final String TAG = "UserAdapter";

private ArrayList<User> mUser;

public UserAdapter(ArrayList<User> user) {
    mUser = user;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public CardView cv;
    public TextView user_name;
    public TextView user_lastName;

    public TextView user_city;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_user);
        user_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name);
        user_lastName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_lastname);
        user_city = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_city);
        Log.d(TAG, "Viewholder");
    }

}

//initialize Viewholder
@Override
public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_person, viewGroup, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");
    return new ViewHolder(mView);
}

//Bind data to view
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.user_name.setText(mUser.get(position).getUser().getFirstname());
    holder.user_lastName.setText(mUser.get(position).getUser().getLastname());
    holder.user_city.setText(mUser.get(position).getUser().getCity());
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");
}

public void setUserList(ArrayList<User> user){
    this.mUser = user;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, user.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void updateData(ArrayList<User> userList) {
    mUser.clear();
    mUser.addAll(userList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    mUser.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount");
    if (mUser == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return mUser.size();
    }
}   }
```

This is the onResponse in the MainActivity:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String responseStr = response.body().string();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type userListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {
                }.getType();
                final ArrayList<User> userList = gson.fromJson(responseStr, userListType);
                CustomMessageEvent event = new CustomMessageEvent();
                event.setUserList(userList);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
                System.out.print(responseStr);
                response.body().close();
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

XML-File (CardView)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                android:id="@+id/rv_user"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                                android:elevation="11dp"
                                android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                                android:theme="@style/AppThemeFSF"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                                app:cardElevation="4dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Nachname"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Stadt"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_lastname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Nachname"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Stadt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Snippet from AS]

[image: Snippet from Logcat]

Thanks in advance guys, have a great day!

Comment: When you're done loading data, update the list inside the adapter with the new data and call notifyItemRangeInserted

Comment: I´ve updated the list but nothing happened.. :( Is it possible, that there´s a general problem with the RecyclerView, cause NOTHING is shown... I see a blank fragment.

Comment: Post the code where you're loading the data and updating the adapter please. Also, post what getItemCount() method returns afterwards.

Comment: I load the data in my MainActivity send it via EventBus to the Fragment and this Fragment listens to the Event and display the ArrayList in the RecyclerView. I´ve updated my original-post...

Comment: Man... I don't see where you update your Adapter. You send your event back to the EventBus, but where is the Subscribe method? Do you update your adapter in this method? You say you send the event to the Fragment, but I don't see a method with the @Subscribe tag in it

Comment: sry @LeandroBorgesFerreira, I was 'out of order' the last two days.. :( you´re right... I´ve got an onEvent-method with the "@Subscribe-tag", but this method is never used! What´s the correct way to use the "@Subscribe-tag" respectively WHERE to use it? Directly in the Fragment or is it the better way to use it in the Adapter?

Comment: I created an answer. I hope it helps!

Comment: I don't see the closing tag for the card view. Can you see the layout in the preview of AS?

Comment: oh.. that's probably a copy-paste error! Like I said, I can see the cards in the AS, also the right count of the cards with all "static" textviews and the dummy-image, only the dynamic text from the viewholder is not shown. UPDATED a screenshot from AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys... I´ve got the solution! And this drives me a bit crazy... The problem was not the Adapter or the ViewHolder or anything inside the Fragment. The "real" problem was the text-size from the TextView inside the CardView-Elements. I deleted this properties and now every single dataset is available! 
Thank you so much for your help and your tips! You´re great!

HAPPY coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not subscribing to receive you event back. So, when you call:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
```

No one is getting the event! And you are not populating you list. So your adapter has nothing to show.

Subscribe for the event like this:

```
@Subscribe
public void receiveEvent(CustomMessageEvent event){
    mAdapter.updateData(event.getUserList())
}
```

This method should be in your fragments. If you put this inside your adapter you are going to violate the single responsibility principle. The only responsibility that your adapter should have is to link the list to the RecyclerView.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So... your suggestion is the "main-way" to work with eventbus and so i did it the first time(s). Now I changed all the stuff in my code to your solution but nothing changes :( It´s crazy... I still only see the empty cards inside my RecyclerView! I´ve logged all methods, also the onBindViewHolder and the onEvent (in the Fragment) and I receive the event and I can log the data, but my ViewHolder does not set the data into the fields. I´m freakin out :(

Comment: Can you share the code of the XML of the recycler itens? I think the problem is there.

Comment: Does it work when you use a Stub for the list? Does the list in the subscribe method has valid data?

Comment: I have to test the stub-theory... the data in the list is valid, that´s sure!

Comment: ok... i´ve tested the ViewStub, but there´s no difference :/ I have absolutely no idea, what´s the problem behind it and this makes me sad! :(

Comment: Calm down! That's good! It means that the problem is in your adapter.

Comment: Try to make an adapter for a simple list... Show only the names... Then keep adding the fields. You will find what's wrong.

Comment: I´ve posted the solution ;)